# how to fit 50 columns in modal dialog box using jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

I want to fit the 50 columns of a grid in a dialog box using jqgrid in jsp .

When i click on viewgridrow icon i see all the column names in a single column line with scrollbar.

i want this to be seperated to 2,3 partitions in a dialog box to fit all in the screen size.

Is that possible or is there any way to deal with this requirement?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible by specifying `rowpos` and `colpos` as shown below.

```
colModel += '{"name":"align","value":"string","editrules":{},"editoptions":{},"formoptions":{"rowpos":2,"colpos": 3}},'
colModel += '{"name":"editable","value":"boolean","editrules":{},"editoptions":{},"formoptions":{"rowpos":3,"colpos": 1}},'
```